# Is it possible to smoothly stop keyframe css animation that is triggered on hover?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

This is simple rotation keyframe animation on hover. Works fine starts fine, but when pointer is moved out animation suddenly stops and cube jumps back to initial state. Is it possible with just css to add easing time or anything to smoothen the stopping when pointer is moved out.

```css
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#cube:hover {
  animation: rotating 12s linear infinite;
}

#cube{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background:red;
transition-duration: 3s; /*Doesn't work*/
}


#cubeb {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background:red;
transition: transform 12s linear;
}

#cubeb:hover {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="cube">Jump When hover ends</div>

<br/>
<div id="cubeb">No Jump but does not continuously rotate on hover</div>
```

Comment: *to smoothen the stopping when pointer is moved out* --> describe the behavior you want to have. What if the element already did 5 full rotation?

Comment: Stop at full rotation or where it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `animation-play-state`

```css
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#cube:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

#cube {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: rotating 12s linear infinite paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="cube">Jump When hover ends</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add an easing effect to the rotation animation so that it smoothens the transition when the pointer is moved out.

You can the **ease-in-out** timing function, which gradually speeds up and then slows down the rotation:

```
#cube:hover {
  animation: rotating 12s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

You can also adjust the duration of the easing effect:

```
#cube:hover {
  animation: rotating 12s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1.0) infinite;
}
```

Comment: Sudden jump is still there when mouse is moved out.